# PHP - file_get_contents doesn't work

Tags: php

How can I solve the problem of below code? This code gets all links in a website but it doesn't work on some website like the below one. How can I solve this problem?

```
<?php

    $html = file_get_contents('http://blogfa.com/members/updated.aspx');

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    // grab all the on the page
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

    for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
        $href = $hrefs->item($i);
        $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
        echo $url . '<br />';
    }

?>
```

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I don't get any error. Nothing print in page.

Comment: remove `@` symbol from this line `@$dom->loadHTML($html);` to see the current reality

Answer (score 1):

Actually You are gettting links..But there is a warning ..To Solve this U have to add one line ..
I am getting this warning

E_WARNING : type 2 -- DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <body> tag in Entity, line: 20 -- at line 6

Solution :

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://blogfa.com/members/updated.aspx');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    echo $url . '<br />';
}
?>
```

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); is used for disable the warning..

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I get the following PHP error:

```
E_WARNING : type 2 -- DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <body> tag in Entity, line: 20 -- at line 6
```

If you look at the sourcecode of your page at http://blogfa.com/members/updated.aspx, you'll see that the `<body>`-tag is opened twice.

Try removing the second `<body>`-tag. Other than this, your code seems to work.